# Qual a forma mais correta de fazer uma consulta com LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta LINQ no meu BD SQL Server, porém o resultado dele sempre vem 'null'. Preciso do primeiro ID do usuário no qual faço a consulta.

Esta é a forma que tento fazer a consulta:

```
public decimal GetCustomerBalance(long accountCurrentAdvisorId)
    {
        var result = this.Table.Select(x => x.AccountCurrentAdvisorId == accountCurrentAdvisorId);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Isto não é bem uma consulta LINQ. Isto é uma consulta usando métodos de extensão. [LINQ é outra coisa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Precisa fazer isto:

```
public decimal GetCustomerBalance(long accountCurrentAdvisorId) {
    return this.Table.Where(x => x.AccountCurrentAdvisorId == accountCurrentAdvisorId)
                     .Select(x => x.CustomerBalance).First();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FilterFirst.cs).

Assim você faz um filtro com o `Where`, depois seleciona a informação que deseja pegar - eu chutei que seria `CustomerBalance` - e finalmente pega o primeiro resultado da sequência gerada (mesmo que ela já tenha só um elemento, afinal você quer um elemento e não uma sequência contendo um elemento, que são dados bem diferentes).

A *query* interna provável gerada será algo assim:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CustomerBalance FROM Table WHERE AccountCurrentAdvisorId = @accountCurrentAdvisorId
```

Comment: Obrigado @bigown

Answer (score 5):

Eu faria assim:

```
public decimal GetCustomerBalance(long accountCurrentAdvisorId) {
    return (from table in this.Table where table.AccountCurrentAdvisorId == accountCurrentAdvisorId select table).First();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Está retornado Null porque você está comparando um LONG com INT, experimente fazer dessa forma.

```
public decimal GetCustomerBalance(int accountCurrentAdvisorId)
{
    return this.Table.Where(x => x.AccountCurrentAdvisorId == accountCurrentAdvisorId)
                 .Select(x => x.AccountCurrentAdvisorId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```